# Scability of .NET webservices

Tags: c#, web-services, scalability

Can anyone help me with a question about webservices and scalability? I have written a webservice as a facade into our document management system and need to think about scalability issues. What areas should I be looking at to ensure performance and availability?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of scalability are you thinking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance is separate from scalability. Scalability means that you can add more servers to linearly increase system throughput (i.e more client connections). The best way to start is having stateless webservices. That way any client can call any of the n webservice intance on n different machines. If there is a shared database at the end for persistence that will ultimately be your bottleneck. There are ways to reduce that with data partitioning and sharding, but only when you get to that point.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, decide what is acceptable behaviour of your web service.  What should it be able to cope - 1000 connections per second?  What response time will each connection have?

Then you need to automate the usage of your web service so you can stress test the system.

What happens when you have 100 requests per second?  1000?  10000?

Then you can make a decision about if performance is ok, if the acceptable behaviour is too strict, or if you need to do heavy performance tuning based on actual profiling data.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking to host your WCF service in IIS. IIS has a lot of performance, scalability, security etc. mechanisms built in and is the best starting point to save you reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Have you done this before? Where can I find information about it?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the performance is certainly due to your own code, but lets assume that it's already optimized.  At that point, the additional performance scaling issues involve the service host (e.g. IIS) the machines that host it, and their network (inter/intranet) connection speeds.  You'll need to do some speed tests to be sure of things.

Answer (score 0):

Well it really depends on what you're doing in your web service, but the only way you're going to find out is by simulating lots of users and measuring it.

Take a look at my answer to this question: [Measuring performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109343/is-there-any-way-to-profile-performance-of-a-wcf-application)

When we tested our code in this manor (where the web services were hosted in Windows service(s)), we found that the bottleneck was authenticating each user in the facade service. In particular the windows component [LSASS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Security_Authority_Subsystem_Service) was using most of the CPU.
Luckily we were able to create new machines, each with a facade service, which then called through to our main set of web services. This enable us to scale up to a large number of users (in the region of 100,000 users using our software normally).